# How to merge reputation of my old account to new account

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, merge-accounts

I have an old account which is blocked on stack overflow which have 92 reputations. and i have created a new account on stack and now i want to merge my previous account reputations into my new account.Please any tell me how this will be done.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your old account? What exactly do you mean when you say that your old account is blocked?

Comment: Mean i from my old account i am unable to ask any question.When i click on ask question this message shows.`Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.` i don't know why this happening

Comment: This is link of my old account.`http://stackoverflow.com/users/1685991/user1685991`

Comment: No, that's the link to *this* account. What's the other one?

Comment: Yes This is my new account link `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1819920/user1819920`

Comment: Creating another account to avoid a question block is not acceptable behavior.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Comment: @animuson Not that it's gonna matter. Assuming the question-ban equation only takes into account posts, then once it's merged, the merged account is gonna be question-banned as well since there aren't any posts in the new account.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "user merge" help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Note that this means a complete user merge, not just reputation.

Comment: sir i am unable to login into both accounts which i want to merge.coz when add login from my login the stack logout the first loged in account and then login the new account

Comment: @user1685991 Then take another look at that help page. Click where it says "click here" and fill out the form. Make sure you follow all of the instructions and edit both profiles to confirm account ownership.

Comment: Sir I filled the form with both accounts with additional information but when click on submit request stack shows this error message `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`

Comment: @user1685991 Alright, let's skip that. Edit both accounts to say "merge me" in the "About me" section and let me know when that's been done.

Comment: Yes I Edit About Me Section and wrote Merge me in it.So plz tell me what will be happen now?

Comment: Now your accounts are one again. This includes reputation, questions, answers, etc. Please don't create another account to get around a question block. [Learn how to get it lifted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) instead.

Comment: Ok will U Please tell me How can i unblock my account to ask questions again

Comment: @user1685991, read the link that Anna just posted, just above this comment. Read it completely, and follow its recommendations.

Comment: @AdamLear i am trying to merging my accounts..i got mail from SO "log into each profile and edit the "About Me" section of each profile to say “merge me""..can you tell what to do

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan Log into each of the accounts you're trying to merge and edit your profile to say "merge me".